# (React) Correct way to typecheck array of objects that may be empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a prop that is usually an array of objects, but sometimes (including on the component's first render) the array is empty. I know that using PropTypes.array is frowned upon and I should use PropTypes.arrayOf() instead, but if I use PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object), there is a failed prop type warning due to the empty state of the array. What is the correct way to type check this prop?

Comment: You can define defaultProps to an empty array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't be getting an error unless you set `isRequired` on it. That is,

```
myArray: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired
```

This will require an array but not necessarily an object. It's how you would handle exactly the case you mention where initially you may pass an empty array.